# Store multiple images with Vuex and FIrebase. (wait for images to upload)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage, vuex

I've got a **working solution** for uploading multiple images to firebase. I get the images from a vue-croppa plugin, which works excellent with phones. 
I generate BLOB-files for all images. Then I upload them to firebase storage, and recieve a url which I put inside the object in database. (This is a project for registring tools).

Vuex-code (JS):

```
createTool ({ commit }, payload) {
  let toolData = {
    croppas: payload.croppas,
    title: payload.title
  }
  var imageURLS = []
  // for Each image in images (croppas (plugin for vue btw) to get blob(s))
  toolData.croppas.forEach(file => {
      file.generateBlob(
          blob => {
            if (blob != null) {
            let rand = (Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 16) + Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 16)).toUpperCase()
            let imageRef = firebase.storage().ref('toolImages/').child(rand)
            imageRef.put(blob)
              .then( data => {
                imageRef.getDownloadURL()
                  .then( downloadURL => {
                  imageURLS.push(downloadURL)
                })
            })
          }     
          })
  })

  const mergedToolData = {
    title: payload.title,
    URLS: imageURLS
  }

  firebase.database().ref('tools').push(mergedToolData)
    .then((data) => {
      const key = data.key
      commit('createTool', {
        title: payload.title,
        URLS: imageURLS,
        id: key
      })
    })
},
```

The images gets uploaded, and I recieve the downloadURL which I store in imageURLS []. **The challenge is** that the code doesn't wait for the for-loop to finish and retrieve all the URLS before uploading the "tools"-data to the database. Therefor the URLS don't get registred to the tool. 
I think the solution would be a async-wait system, but i'm really not sure how I would do that.

Here is a .vue file for testing:

```
     <template>
      <v-layout column align-center>
        <v-flex xs12 sm6 class="mt-5">
          <croppa v-for="(c, i) in croppas"
            :key="i"
            v-model="croppas[i]"
            :width="300"
            :height="300"
            :placeholder="'Choose an image'"
            @new-image="croppas.push({})"
            v-show="i === croppas.length - 1 || c.imageSet">
          </croppa>
          <croppa
            :v-if="this.croppas == ''"
            :width="300"
            :height="300"
            :placeholder="'Choose an image'"
            @new-image="croppas.push({})">
          </croppa>
          </v-flex>
          <v-flex xs12 class="my-4">
            <v-btn @click="onCreateTool" color="#D08513" dark class="darkCustomBtn">Upload</v-btn>
            <v-btn to="/tools" flat class="customBtn ml-3" >Cancel</v-btn>
          </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </template>

    <script>
    export default {
      data () {
        return {
          title: '',
          croppas: []
        }
      },
      methods: {
        onCreateTool() {      
          this.$store.dispatch('createTool', { croppas: this.croppas, title: this.title })

        }
      }
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

An answer already exists : [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52898599/how-to-upload-multiple-images-to-firebase-storage-and-return-multiple-downloadur).
The exactly what you're looking for :).
It's one on many ways to do it, but this one is really on the code and have a google error handler.

Comment: Thank you. I will spend some more time looking for similar problems before posting, next time :)
Shoud I delete this post then?

Comment: No, it's not necessary :). Hope it can help someone else ^^.
If you want another way to solve this problem, you could use `Array` and `for loop` with multiple files form :).